# Getting wrong answer in Partition Equal Subset sum on GFG

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the [partition equal subset problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subset-sum-problem2014/1#) on GFG. I am aware of the correct way of doing this via reducing it to the [subset sum problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/). However, I had another approach in mind and I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

I have maintained two sum variables: partition1 and partition2, and at every recursive call the element under consideration can go to either one of those. I am checking if both the sums become equal at any time, and if so I return 1. Here is the my code for the same:

```
int traverse(int N,int arr[],int partition1,int partition2, int curr){
    
    if(partition1==partition2 and partition1!=0)
        return 1;
        
        
    if(curr>=N)
        return 0;
    
    //cout<<partition1<<" "<<partition2<<endl;    
    return traverse(N,arr,partition1+arr[curr],partition2,curr+1) or traverse(N,arr,partition1,partition2+arr[curr],curr+1);
}
```

Currently I am only concerned about the recurrence and not the optimal approach of converting it to a DP solution, as it is giving wrong answer even for this input :

9(Number of elements)

75 131 977 305 220 957 47 56 840(The input Array)

The expected output is NO, but my code is giving output YES. Can anyone help me in figuring out what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: doesn't your first `if` also need to check that all the numbers have been used i.e. `curr == N`?

Comment: what does `or` do in recursion call?

Comment: @AnkitMishra `or` is an [alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) for `||`

Comment: I know. Write it separately and remove or.

Comment: @AnkitMishra I think the idea is to return `true` if either branch returns `true`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles you are right I overlooked that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement:

```
if(partition1==partition2 and partition1!=0)
    return 1;
```

can potentially make the function return 1 prematurely, since partition1 can still be equal to partition2 before all numbers have been traversed. The following modification to your code resolves the issue:

```
int traverse(int N, int arr[], int partition1, int partition2, int curr) {

    if (curr >= N)
        return partition1 == partition2 && partition1 != 0;
   
    return traverse(N, arr, partition1 + arr[curr], partition2, curr + 1) || traverse(N, arr, partition1, partition2 + arr[curr], curr + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the mistake.